# Angular material integrating `ng-content` within popup modal

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-template

there a popup, which should include multiple component using the "" with assinged id. it's  not working. I am trying to add a selected 'header' inside the div containing a border. but not working. I am much confused. need the help.

click on open button.

[Live URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsymdn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

app.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childTemplate') childTemplate: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(HelloComponent, {
      data: {
        name: 'popup',
        pagecontent: this.childTemplate,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

pop component:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not forget about `ng-content` and just use the ng-template to render the desired output?

Comment: @NarenMurali, I am fine. but got no idea. In the popup i required to show mutiple component with appropriate selectors.

Comment: is this the desired output [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g1n1hj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an array of template and just use `*ngFor` to render the templates

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childTemplate') childTemplate: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;
  @ViewChild('childTemplate2') childTemplate2: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;
  @ViewChild('childTemplate3') childTemplate3: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(HelloComponent, {
      data: {
        name: 'popup',
        pagecontents: [
          this.childTemplate,
          this.childTemplate2,
          this.childTemplate3,
        ],
      },
    });
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g1n1hj)

Comment: I agree. I though the same. but i looked for very simple and reusable approach. thanks